# Look Up JavaEE Beans Without Knowing Implementation

Tags: java, wildfly, javabeans

I want to look up JavaEE beans without knowing any of the details of their implementation so that I can swap out the implementation of the beans without needing to edit anything beyond the bean I want to swap in.  It looks to me like there isn't any way to do this, but that seems strange to me.  Is there a way to do this and if so, how?

What I thought would work:

These are all deployed to a single Wildfly Instance, with all wars depending on the jar.

Jar:

```
@Remote
public interface MyLovelyInterface{
    public int doLovelyThings(int a);
}

@Remote
public interface MyEvilInterface{
    public int doEvilThings(int a);
}
```

War1:

```
@Singleton
public Class LovelyBean implements MyLovelyInterface{
    ....//Implementation
}
```

War2:

```
@Singleton
public Class EvilBean implements MyEvilInterface{
    @EJB
    MyLovelyInterface myLovelyInterface;
    ....//Implementation
}
```

Since I'm asking the question this obviously didn't work.  At deploy time I get the following exception:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0406: No EJB found with interface of type 'com.mybiz.MyLovelyInterface' for binding com.mybiz.EvilBean/myLovelyInterface
```

I've tried adding several combinations of annotations, doing things like naming the bean and specifying the lookup, naming the bean and looking up the bean by name, and specifying the implementation as the remote bean, but they all give the same error.  I suspect I'm missing something important because looking up a bean by it's interface so you don't need to know anything of the implementation feels like it should be the base case.

Comment: You have 2 wars and they don't see each others: you have to enable war2 to 'see' war1 by using a jboss-deployment-structure.xml and tells war2 that it depends on war1.

Comment: @ehsavoie This could work, but then I have to specify the wars by name, and I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that it is possible to make classes in one WAR accessible from another WAR. The [Classloading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) document makes this clear for EAR files:

> The ear-subdeployments-isolated element value has no effect on the isolated classloader of the .war file(s). i.e. irrespective of whether this flag is set to true or false, the .war within a .ear will have a isolated classloader and other sub-deployments within that .ear will not be able to access classes from that .war. This is as per spec.

and I think that this also applies to isolated deployments. This does not apply to JAR files.

You will need to perform complete remote EJB lookups (as per [Remote EJB invocations via JNDI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project) in order to accomplish your requirement. But you need to be aware that this capability may disappear from one WildFly version to another because RMI between WAR files is not mandated by the Java EE specifications. It just happens to work in WildFly right now.

Comment: To clarify, I WANT to do the lookups, but I want to be able to do them without needing any details of the war that provided the beans.

Comment: but you're using @EJB, you will need to do it by 'hand' i think